# What happens to Kinesis data when no consumers are attached?

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I set up a new Kinesis Data Stream and wrote some data to it. Then I realized I hadn't set up Kinesis Firehose yet, so I set that up too. I expected Firehose to collect the data that had been written into the stream previously and dump it into S3, but I found that Firehose only dumped data that was written to the stream after it was attached.

What happens to data that is written to a Kinesis Data Stream when there are no consumers attached? The stream is configured with a retention period of 24 hours, so I assume the data is still in there somewhere (at least for now). Is it still there, and is there some way for me to get at it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the data remains in the Kinesis stream until the retention period expires.

Unfortunately, it's not accessible with Kinesis Firehose. When Firehose initializes its shard iterators, it uses mode `LATEST` to begin picking up data the moment it starts to run. There doesn't seem to be any way to configure Firehose to pick up records that were sent to Kinesis from earlier.

However! It is totally possible to extract the data from the Kinesis stream using any process that can initialize a shard iterator in `TRIM_HORIZON` or `AT_TIMESTAMP` mode. This can be done with `awscli`, but I ended up writing a Python script with boto3 to capture the data from the shard. It looked something like this.

```py
response = client.get_shard_iterator(
    StreamName=StreamName,
    ShardId=ShardId,
    ShardIteratorType='AT_TIMESTAMP',
    Timestamp=datetime(2020, 4, 7, 1, 0, 0),
)

while True:
    response = client.get_records(
        ShardIterator=ShardIterator,
        Limit=150
    )
    if response['MillisBehindLatest'] == 0:
        break
    for record in response['Records']:
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(record['Data'])
    ShardIterator = response['NextShardIterator']
```

Also beware: if the iterator starts at a time when no data is available, `get_records()` may return an empty set of zero records `[]` for many iterations until the iterator catches up to the time when there is data. This happened to me every time I used `TRIM_HORIZON`, and that's why I switched to using `AT_TIMESTAMP` so I could jump right to where the data started.